# Kotlin how can i change a color of a BarChart using mpandroidchart

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the problem that I only give one color for an entry

```
val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()

entries.add(BarEntry(1f, floatArrayOf(richtig, richtig, richtig, falsch, falsch, richtig, richtig, richtig, falsch)))


val set = BarDataSet(entries,"richtig")
set.color = -65536
val set2 = BarDataSet(entries,"falsch")
set2.color = -16711936
```

How can I give `richtig` a green color and `falsch` a red color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Color.parseColor("#FF0000")
```

or

```
Color.rgb(255,00,00)
```

for red color. For green:

```
Color.parseColor("#00FF00")
```

or

```
Color.rgb(00,255,00)
```